# An inequality about a quadratic polynomial

Tags: inequality, polynomials

In a paper, I faced the following statement:
$$(x_1 + x_2)^4 \leq 16(x_1^4+x_2^4)$$

Because there is no explanation, I thought that showing the inequality may be a trivial one. But, I failed to show the relationship.

Thus, why the statement above holds?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2302845/42969

Comment: Or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2068562/42969

Comment: You need to use the convexity of $x^4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a hint:  $$(x_1+x_2)\leq 2\max \{ x_1,x_2\}$$ can you take over ?

Comment: Lol, thank you for the simple and clear answer:)

Comment: How is this helpful? Do you intend to take the 4th power of both sides? But this destroys the inequality as $x_1, x_2$ may be negative.

Comment: @Desperado  $$|x_1+x_2| \leq (|x_1|+|x_2|) \leq 2 \max \{ (|x_1|, |x_2|\}$$